# C syntax parser

Tags: c, compiler-construction, code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

Are there any libs out there that can parse C syntax?

For example I would like to write my own code/scripts that will analyze c files given the c syntax. Number of "if" statements per function/file, lines of comments per lines of code in a function and so on.....

I have no problem writing all this custom code just wanted to make the job easier if there was already some lib that I can use to jump start instead of starting with the parser.

Thanks!

Comment: I think using `clang` as a library might work.

Comment: Hmm I don't see how to do this with clang. For example count the number of "if" statements in a function.

Comment: @jox, clang can definitely what you're looking for.  It does contain a full C parser, after all.

Comment: Older versions of clang had an XML AST printer backend (which was later removed, unfortunately, for no reason). It is relatively easy to take that XML backend and reapply it to the newer clang.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the `clang` suggestion already made, consider [pycparser](https://code.google.com/p/pycparser/) and [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/wave/index.html).

Comment: Brian, pycparser is exactly what I am after. Very simple and easy. Is there something that simple for c/c++? If not I will hack something up with Python.

Comment: You will likely find that "hacking something up" for C++ is notoriously difficult and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Although they are more targeted at semantical analyses rather than syntactical ones, you might be interested in [CIL](http://kerneis.github.com/cil/) and [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/), which is based on it (both in OCaml). Another tool (OCaml and Python bindings) of interest is [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would look first for an existing tool to do what you want. This sounds like an awful lot of work and there are a lot of good free tools out there for code metrics (did you look on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)?).

If you insist on going ahead with your project, you might google for Lex/Yacc grammars for C.

However, I switched from Lex/Yacc a few years ago to [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). I particularly like the way it allows you [visually step through your parsing](http://www.antlr.org/works/movies/debugger.mp4).

A great tool, and free. There is a [complete grammar for C](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g) available too, so you can modify that to suit your needs.

Hope this helps. Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

you might also consider trying a code coverage tool. although code coverage is meant to show you how much percent of the source code is executed but some of them also show how many conditional statements or loops it encountered whilst doing code coverage. One example that I can share based on my experience is windriver workbench code coverage tool